# Mathematical function for checking if list is a palindrome

Tags: haskell, math

I've been experimenting with Haskell today and wrote a function that checks whether a list of integers is a palindrome. I think that it should be possible to write the same function as a mathematical function. Here's my code:

```
isPalindrome :: [Int] -> Bool
isPalindrome x
    | length x <= 1 = True
    | head x == last x = isPalindrome (init (tail x))
    | otherwise = False
```

I tried writing a function by googling it together and ended up with this:

[image: Function in mathematical notation]

I'm really not sure whether this is the correct way/whether there is a correct way/whether there is a way and I would like to know it and I'd also appreciate feedback on the code

Comment: It is not very efficient, since using `last` requires *O(n)* time, `length` and `init` a well.

Comment: As a general recommendation, avoid `length, !!, head, tail, init, last`. Using pattern matching, recursion, and some user-defined (or library) auxiliary functions you can solve most list-related tasks. There are rare cases where the above functions are OK, but too often they only lead to inefficient, unidiomatic code. Just pretend they don't exist.

Comment: What do you mean *mathematical function*? In what way is your code not one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your mathematical formula, you're close, but there are a couple of problems with it.

When using "x" to represent a vector whose elements are understood to be "x_0, x_1, ..., x_n", the convention is to use boldface for the vector **x** or,  particularly when writing it by hand, to annotate "x" with an straight or squiggly underline, or perhaps a little arrow either above or below it.  Otherwise, it's unclear that "x" is related to the various "x_i".  (There's also the minor matter that the first element of a vector **x** is more often "x_1" than "x_0", though this can vary depending on the particular mathematical field.)

The other problem is that, even with "x" in boldface, |**x**| is not typically used to represent the number of elements in a vector.  It **is** used to represent a vector's "length", which is probably why it came up that way in your Google search, but the "length" of a vector here is not the number of elements (that would be its "dimension"), but rather the geometric length of the vector within some geometric space.

A better way of writing the formula might be:

[image]

This is a reasonable, recursive definition that just about any mathematician would understand.

Unlike cases in Haskell where the "first match" is used, cases in a mathematical formula are usually meant to use conditions that are explicitly mutually exclusive, except for cases labelled "otherwise" or similar, so here the second condition might better be written "n > 1, x_1 /= x_n", even though the "n > 1" would be redundant in Haskell.  However, for this particular function, there isn't much of an ambiguity.  If n=1, then we never have x_1/=x_n`, so it's obvious only the first case can apply, while if n=0, the condition x_1/=x_n doesn't make sense, given there is no x_0 in this version, so again it's obvious that only the first case can apply.

Note that mathematical formulas are typically *less* rigorous than Haskell function definitions, so there's room for disagreement on the "best" way of writing a formula like this, and there's some shared "cultural" knowledge that makes some ambiguous definitions acceptable and others unacceptable.

Answer (score 3):

It is not very efficient, since using `last` requires *(n)* time, `length` and `init` a well.

You can work with [**`reverse :: [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:reverse) to reverse the list and then check if both are the same:

```
isPalindrome :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome x = x == reverse x
```

This will still do a lot of extra work, since halfway the list, we know we are safe. For that we can use a "hare and tortoise" approach to half the list with:

```
half :: [a] -> [a]
half xs = go xs xs
  where
    go (_ : _ : xs) ~(y : ys) = y : go xs ys
    go _ _ = []
```

This will produce for a list of length *n*, a list with the first *⌊n/2⌋* items.

So then we can work with:

```
isPalindrome :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome x = and (zipWith (==) (half x) (reverse x))
```

Comment: I'm not convinced your second version does less work than the first version, unless testing equality is significantly more expensive than other operations.

Comment: @Stef: well for `Int`s likely not, if we are checking equality of binary trees for example, then that might take some work. It at least reduces the number of equality checks to a minimum, the implementation of `(==)` is here something we don't have control over. We have control over `half` itself, so that will take *O(n)*, and therefore the performance might not per see be better in general, but less likely produce outliers.

Comment: Haven't seen this "hare and tortoise" approach before. Nice one!

Comment: `reverse` is also O(n). The difference here is not the asymptotics of the function you're calling, but how many times you're calling it -- you make O(1) calls to `reverse` but the original code makes O(n) calls to `init` and friends.